# Emploi de « e.g. » en français

Tags: latin, abréviations

**E.g.** est fréquemment employé en anglais dans des publications, livres, etc. Venant du latin exemplī gratiā et étant donné la grande influence du latin en français je me demande pourquoi son emploi est rarissime et l'abréviation p. ex. est la règle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le latin a aussi une grande influence sur l'anglais et bien que de nombreuses expressions latines soient utilisées en français comme en anglais, il existe d'autres cas où, sans que l'on puisse identifier de raison particulière, il persiste en anglais alors qu'il est souvent ou toujours remplacé par une forme française :

> c.-à-d. : *i.e.*
>
> Sortie : *exit*
>
> Anciens (élèves) : *alumni*
>
> Avertissement: *caveat*
>
> Vers/environ : *circa*
>
> Émérite : *emeritus*

et donc :

> Par exemple : *e.g.*

Answer (score 0):

Complement à la réponse :

https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/deux-latino-anglicismes-ie-et-eg

> L'Office québécois de la langue française recommande d'utiliser ces
>   abréviations françaises au lieu des anglo-latinismes i.e. et e.g.
>   C'est aussi la position adoptée par Druide informatique et son
>   logiciel Antidote, dont le module correcteur alerte le scripteur qui
>   laisse échapper un i.e. ou un e.g. malencontreux, qu'il peut remplacer
>   automatiquement par l'équivalent français.
>
> Pour conclure, rappelons le principe général voulant qu'une
>   abréviation ne soit utilisée que si le manque d'espace le justifie.

https://lexigramm.com/vocabulaire/ie-et-eg

> Quand et comment utiliser i.e. et e.g. ? Ces deux abréviations sont
>   couramment utilisées par les anglophones et se retrouvent de plus en
>   plus fréquemment dans des textes en français, le plus souvent du fait
>   de mauvaises traductions.
>
> Les deux abréviations pouvant facilement être confondues, il convient
>   en français d’utiliser les abréviations existantes « c-à-d » pour «
>   c'est-à-dire » et « par ex. » pour « par exemple ». Le texte n’en sera
>   que plus lisible.
>
> Comme ces abréviations peuvent tout de même se rencontrer dans des
>   textes en français, sinon en anglais, un bon moyen mémo-technique pour
>   se souvenir de leur signification est de mémoriser « Example Given »
>   (« exemple donné » en anglais) pour e.g.